# Apple Binary Rejected (2.16)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

My app requires users current location to show him direction to a particular location in google map

**Below is the code to show location on web view-**

```
[self.getDirectionsWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,currentLocation.coordinate.longitude,self.projectLatitude,self.projectLongitude]]]];
```

The app declares support for location in .plist by using ***NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription*** and ***NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription***

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Apple rejected the app with following reason

> 2.16 Details
>
> Your app declares support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in
>   your Info.plist file but still does not declare any features that
>   require persistent location. Apps that declare support for location in
>   the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file must have features
>   that require persistent location.
>
> Specifically, we noticed that the Directions feature does not require
>   persistent location information, since it does not include
>   turn-by-turn navigation.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'd say they're asking why do you need location services when you're in the background because you only appear (to the review team) to use it when in the foreground.

Comment: Using [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] instead of [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] might fix it up!

Answer (score 11):

You just remove the location support from `UIBackgroundModes` key in info.plist

As you must only use `UIBackgroundModes` for location when you want to fetch location when your app is in background.

In your app declaration of `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` is enough.

Answer (score 4):

Based on:

- My app requires users current location to **show him direction** to a particular location in google map.
- NSLocation**Always**UsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
- we noticed that the Directions feature **does not require persistent location information,** since it **does not include turn-by-turn navigation**

It looks like they're stating you shouldn't need location information *unless the app is actually active.* Since the location information is used to show the user the direction they need to head in, you should be able to simply adjust (with a little latency of course) when your app comes to the fore.

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22):

> **UIBackgroundModes** (Array - iOS) specifies that the app provides specific background services and must be allowed to continue running while in the background.
>
> These keys should be used sparingly and only by apps providing the indicated services. Where alternatives for running in the background exist, those alternatives should be used instead.
>
> For example, apps can use the significant location change interface to receive location events instead of registering as a background location app.

---

That'd be my analysis though it's equally likely that the reviewer just had an argument with their significant other that morning, and is just being capricious :-) Nah, just joking, but it does sometimes seem to outsiders that the decisions they make are, shall we say, less than perfectly consistent.

Answer (score 1):

It's is not necessary to request the background mode to request the user's current location.

I would recommend to use *NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription* if you don't need to use the user's location in background. Users are more inclined to deny the user location authorization when they see *NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription* because they think that reduce the device's battery